# two values to same key in twig path

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm attempting to pass an array to a parameter in a twig path. 
I need to do include two values for the same key.

I've attempted to do something like this

`path('path_name', {'status': array('req', 'ord')}) }}`

but twig does not seem to like arrays in paths.

I've tried a number of other options.   This doesn't err but of course the second key-value overwrites the first

`path('path_name', {'status': 'req', 'status': 'ord'}) }}`

It doesn't seem to like this either:

`path('path_name', {('status':'req') and ('status': 'ord')})`

Any suggestions?  I'm hoping to avoid rewriting my methods and stay DRY

Comment: What kind of url do you want to generate? Something like `/yourpath?status[]=req&status[]=ord`?

Comment: @AlanT. that's pretty close.   I'm currently generating `/items?status=req` which works fine, but I'd like to include both parameters

Comment: In fact, that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple lists, you need to use [`[]`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#literals) to declare your array in Twig.
The following expression will add both parameters to your query string:

```
{{ path('path_name', {'status': ['req', 'ord']}) }}
```

The generated path will include `status[0]=req&status[1]=ord` in its query string.

Comment: That was it. I knew there was something I was missing.